# why is there a space after console logging with a backslash n?

Tags: javascript, newline

The content after a new line character seems to start with an indent of one space.

```
console.log('foo\n', 'bar');
```

This logs:

```
foo
 bar
```

Why isn't bar directly below foo? How would you log text starting at the same point of the line?

Comment: What does the output look like without the `\n`?

Comment: Line breaks and/or one or more spaces just create a single white space in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `console.log('foo', 'bar');`, it automatically adds a space between these two logs. If you want to exclude this space, just use this:

```js
console.log('foo', '\nbar');
```

It will interpret this as a new line without white space.

Comment: More accurately, a space and then a newline.. so just a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

This is as per behaviour.
In JS if you give a comma separated list to `console.log()` all of them would get printed separated by spaces.

```js
console.log('foo','bar'); 
//foo bar
```

You can use either of the following options below:

```js
console.log('foo','\nbar');

//OR if the above looks too ugly for your taste,

console.log('foo');
console.log('bar');
```